# Possible to upload a public GoogleDoc using Google Docs List API?

Tags: public, google-sheets, google-docs-api

I am creating a web app where I would like the user to be able to manipulate contents of a spreadsheet that do not get saved to the original spreadsheet-- in effect so that multiple users can access the same spreadsheet and the data/formulas contained without interfering with one another.

If my spreadsheet is public, is there a way for users to upload it programmatically using the docs list API? That way they have a copy saved where they can make whatever changes desired.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can copy a spreadsheet by issuing a POST request as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#copying_documents):

```
POST https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full
Authorization: <your authorization header here>
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
[Additional headers]

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>[SELF_LINK_OF_THE_ORIGINAL_DOCUMENT]</id>
  <title>My Copy</title>
</entry>
```